# Multiple AJAX calls in single PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web

I am trying to validate username and email via AJAX frim single JavaScript file and sending data to single PHP file... my code is

HTML code ->

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onBlur="userChk()" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" onBlur="emailchk()" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
```

JavaScript code ->

```
function userChk(){
  var user_name = $('#user_name').val();
      $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'login/signup-fn.php',
        data : { name: user_name},
        success : function(data)
              {
                   $("#result").html(data);
                }
        });
        return false;
  }

  function emailchk(){
  var email = $('#email').val();
      $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'login/signup-fn.php',
        data : {email:email},
        success : function(data)
              {
                   $("#result").html(data);
                }
        });
        return false;
  }
```

PHP code ->

```
include('../components/connectdb.php');
if($_POST['name']) {
    $user_name     = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $uselect_sql= "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='{$user_name}'";

       $uselect_query = mysqli_query($conn, $uselect_sql);

      $urow = mysqli_num_rows($uselect_query);

      if($urow > 0){
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>User Name Already Exist</div>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "";
    }
    }


    else if($_POST['email']){
      $email = ($_POST['email']);
       $eselect_sql= "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";

       $eselect_query = mysqli_query($conn, $eselect_sql);

      $erow = mysqli_num_rows($eselect_query);
      if($erow > 0){
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Warning!</strong>Email Already Exist</div>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "";
    }
    }
```

I don't know where's the mistalke... I am new in web devlopment.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `strip_tags` is not an adequate protection method.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")`

Comment: What is the problem here? Issues with SQL injection aside, that could could work. Have a look at your JavaScript console and network inspector to see if those calls are being triggered correctly, plus check your web server's error log for any notifications.

Comment: Please provide the name of the file in which the html+js reside AND please provide the name of the file in which the php code reside.

Comment: ... and you forgot to describe what the problem is.

Comment: Check your browser console for a network error, check what `data` contains in the callback or, in the worst case comment all coincidences of `$_POST['name']`, specify a `name` but manually and access it from the browser, some PHP errors could come up. Apart from all that, you should improve your code, specially for preventing SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `isset()` else it ll throw undefined index error. Because suppose when the ajax call for name check will call email variable would not set so it ll throw error undefined index email.

`if($_POST['name'])` will not check for undefined variable.

```
include('../components/connectdb.php');
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $user_name     = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $uselect_sql= "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='{$user_name}'";

       $uselect_query = mysqli_query($conn, $uselect_sql);

      $urow = mysqli_num_rows($uselect_query);

      if($urow > 0){
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>User Name Already Exist</div>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "";
    }
    }


    else if(isset($_POST['email'])){
      $email = ($_POST['email']);
       $eselect_sql= "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";

       $eselect_query = mysqli_query($conn, $eselect_sql);

      $erow = mysqli_num_rows($eselect_query);
      if($erow > 0){
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Warning!</strong>Email Already Exist</div>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "";
    }
    }
```